# Rails 4.2 web-console issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rails-console, ruby-on-rails-4.2

After upgrading to Rails 4.2, I was excited to try out the newly integrated web-console, but I'm having some issues.

In the release notes for Rails 4.2, it mentions: "New applications generated with Rails 4.2 now come with the Web Console gem by default."

Since I upgraded to 4.2, I assume that means I will still have to specify it in my Gemfile.  Without adding it to my Gemfile, rails just gives me "undefined local variable or method `console'" so I assume that to be the case.

Once I added gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0' to the Gemfile, and run rails server, I now get:

```
/home/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/binding_of_caller-0.7.3.pre1/lib/binding_of_caller/mri2.rb:21:in `callers': uninitialized constant RubyVM::DebugInspector (NameError)
  from /home/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/better_errors-2.0.0/lib/better_errors/exception_extension.rb:7:in `set_backtrace'
  from /home/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
  from /home/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
  from /home/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
  from /home/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
  from /home/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
  from /home/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
  from /home/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler.rb:133:in `require'
  from /home/kevin/workspace/applications/ems-heroes/config/application.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
  from /home/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
  from /home/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
  from /home/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
  from /home/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
  from /home/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
  from /home/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  from bin/rails:4:in `require'
  from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I googled around and didnt find much. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: did you do the bundle dance to complete the upgrade?  and do you `rake rails:update` ?

Comment: also there is an open issue about web_console and better_errors now working, but the error is different from yours.

Comment: I did do the bundle dance and got through a couple minor issues there.  I also stepped through rake rails:update after you mentioned it. Still didn't solve this error :(

Comment: The only other thing I would try is removing better_errors temp, and see if that fixes the error, as I am not sure how well they get along...

Comment: Just tried that. No cigar :(  Thanks anyway @Doon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turned out that my issue was coming from the dependency 'debug_inspector'.

Thanks to this: https://github.com/banister/binding_of_caller/issues/39

I just had to run:

```
$ gem uninstall debug_inspector
$ bundle install
```